# HTTP_REFERER substitute that IE 6 will provide?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, http, http-referer

So IE (6, at least) won't help me with `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` that I request with PHP.

But I'm new to JavaScript and have just used a little routine in a pop-up to *refresh* the page from which the popup was called (i.e. parent). Works beautifully in Firefox, Safari, etc.

There's NO security issue - I'd just like to the user loaded in the window is URL of page from which the pop-up (for editing) was called. (and not the pop-up's URL).

Am I forced to *send* the URL in a GET when I link to the pop-up?

Comment: Just a note: "parent" isn't really the right word, you want the "opener".  "parent" is used for frames.

Answer (score 2):

You can't rely on any browser sending the HTTP_REFERER.

To refresh a parent window, do:

```
window.opener.location.reload()
```

In other cases, use a PHP session instead of relying on the referrer.

Comment: window.opener.location.reload(true) will force it to re-fetch rather than use the cache

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for IE to pass the referer on JavaScript transitions.

See here:
http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2008/11/bug-421-ie-fails-to-pass-http-referer.html

Works in IE6, IE7, and IE8

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, document.referrer works as well in javascript. But in this example, you should definitely use gnud's method, taking into cacount RoBorg's comment.